# Loading Font Resource and Setting Baseline

Tags: wpf, xaml, fonts

Is there a way to load a font as a resource and set its baseline?

The following works:

```
<FontFamily x:Key="DefaultFontFamily">/Swift.UiResources;component/Resources/Fonts/#Meta Offc</FontFamily>
```

But adding the baseline like so:

```
<FontFamily x:Key="DefaultFontFamily" Baseline="0.9">/Swift.UiResources;component/Resources/Fonts/#Meta Offc</FontFamily>
```

Results in the following error:

```
TypeConverter syntax error encountered while processing intialization string '/Swift.UiResources;component/Resources/Fonts/#Meta Offc'. Element attributes are not allowed on objects created via TypeConverter.
```

I should point out that the problem I'm trying to solve is that the font handed down from marketing, when centered vertically, is render higher than the previous font.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a composite font, and have all Unicode ranges map to your embedded font.  You'll need to create a new file with a `.CompositeFont` extension, and give it a Build Action of "Resource".  Its contents should be:

```
<!-- File: "Resources/Fonts/Custom Font.CompositeFont" in Swift.UiResources -->
<FontFamily xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/composite-font"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
            xmlns:s="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
            Baseline="0.9">
  <FontFamily.FamilyNames>
    <s:String x:Key="en-US">Custom Font</s:String>
  </FontFamily.FamilyNames>

  <FontFamily.FamilyMaps>
    <FontFamilyMap Scale="1.0"
                   Target="/Swift.UiResources;component/Resources/Fonts/#Meta Offc"
                   Unicode="0000-007F" />
  </FontFamily.FamilyMaps>
</FontFamily>
```

Then, when referencing your font in Xaml, use this format:

```
/Swift.UiResources;component/Resources/Fonts/#Custom Font
```

The font name following the `#` should match the value you set in `FontFamily.FamilyNames` above.

If you want to map more than the standard ASCII range, you can add more comma-separated character ranges to the `Unicode` property.

In the past, I have noticed that when you create a composite font that uses a resource URI in one or more of its mappings, it doesn't display properly in the Visual Studio designer, though it works properly at runtime.  They may have fixed this since I reported it.

Comment: It doesn't look like the `Target` property supports URIs in the same way as `FontFamily` does.  I can specify `"Arial"`, but not `"./#Meta Off"`.

Comment: Turns out you were partially right.  When I couldn't get a simple sample to work, I remembered that the `Target` only seems to handle URIs when the composite font is defined as its own resource.  See updated answer.

Comment: Wow, thanks!  Neither MSDN nor Google were any help in finding detailed information related to `FamilyNames` and `FamilyMaps`.  Where did you learn this stuff?

Comment: I was browsing my `Windows\Fonts` folder one day, saw some `.CompositeFont` files in there, and decided to do some experimentation :).  The composite fonts that ship with WPF have some useful comments.